# Binding to other control's selected value

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a wpf application using caliburn.micro.
It has a datagrid and a combobox.

Here is the DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TriageMapRecords"
          Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          BaseControls:DataGridExtension.Columns="{Binding TriageMapRecordColumns}"
          CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTriageMapRecord, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

SelectedTriageMapRecord object contains a field CounterpartyNameId.

I want to bind selected value in the combobox to CounterpartyNameId of the SelectedTriageMapRecord.

I tried this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="RefCounterparties" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Source=SelectedTriageMapRecord, 
                                  Path=CounterpartyNameId, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Width="Auto" MinWidth="100" Margin="3,3,0,3"/>
```

But this didn't work. Could you tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you probably want to do it like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="RefCounterparties"  
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id"  
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTriageMapRecord.CounterpartyNameId,  
                                  Mode=TwoWay}" 
          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
          Width="Auto" MinWidth="100" Margin="3,3,0,3"/>
```

You don't want to set a source because your source is still the `DataContext`. Then you specify the path on the `DataContext` to drill down into. In this case, the `SelectedTriageMapRecord` property of the `DataContext`, and then the `CounterpartyNameId` property of the `SelectedTriageMapRecord` object.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked. Could you please tell in what situation I would use that Source?

Comment: You use Source or ElementName if you want the Binding to look at something other than its inherited DataContext. One example would be if you were binding to something that was in the Resources for the Window or UserControl. For more information, take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source.aspx